# Reality check: $\mathbb E \{ B_s B_t ^2\}=0 $

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I desire to calculate   $\mathbb E \{ B_s B_t ^2\} $, where $B$ is a standard brownian motion starting from zero. I want to be sure I am not making any mistake on both reasoning and result, even if I calculated it by three differents methods.

**1° solution:**

If $s\leq t$, then we have 
 \begin{align}\mathbb E \{ B_s B_t ^2\}  &= \mathbb E \{ B_s (B_t ^2-t)\} \\&= \mathbb E \{ B_s \mathbb E \{(B_t ^2-t) | \mathcal F_s\}\} \\&= \mathbb E \{ B_s (B_s ^2-s)\} \\&= \mathbb E \{ B_s ^3\} \\&=s^{3/2}\mathbb E \{ B_1 ^3\} =0\end{align}

If $t\leq s$, then we have 
 \begin{align}\mathbb E \{ B_s B_t ^2\}  &= \mathbb E \{ B_t ^2\mathbb E \{ B_s | \mathcal F_t\}\} \\&= \mathbb E \{ B_t ^3\} =0\end{align}

**2° solution:**

We know that $B^2_t = t +2 \int_0^t B_u ~dB_u$ and $B_s =  \int_0^s  ~dB_u$ then

\begin{align}\mathbb E \{ B_s B_t ^2\}  &= 2 E \{\int_0^s  ~dB_u\int_0^t B_u ~dB_u\}  \\&=2 E \{\int_0^{t\wedge s}  B_u ~du\}  \\&=\int_0^{t\wedge s}  2 E \{B_u\} ~du =0\end{align}

**3° solution:**

It's trivial that $\mathbb E \{ B_s B_t ^2\} =0$ since  $B_t^2 \geq 0$ and the brownian motion is gaussien process so it has symetric law.

I will be thankful for any feedback.

Comment: Both approaches seem good to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third solution uses a good idea but it needs to be slightly reformulated: the distributions of the processes $(B_t)_{t\geqslant0}$ and $(-B_t)_{t\geqslant0}$ are the same hence, for every $(s,t)$, the distributions of $(B_s,B_t)$ and $(-B_s,-B_t)$ are the same hence the distributions of  $B_sB_t^2$ and $(-B_s)(-B_t)^2=-B_sB_t^2$ are the same, that is, the distribution of $B_sB_t^2$ is symmetric. In particular, it has  mean zero.

Comment: Thank you for the formalization.